# Eager Learners vs. Lazy Learners in terms of generalization

Tags: algorithm, classification, data-mining

According to books on Data Mining "**Lazy Learners classify objects without generalization step.**"

What I need to know is - given a situation where the data set is limited in size and accuracy is important with a very low false positive rate (we can compromise on speed needed for creation of models etc.), what would be preferable - Lazy learner or Eager Learner ? Assume the data set not to be very high dimensional.

Comment: both can be utilized for this, for example, you can use KNN as lazy learner. If low FP is very important, you can choose that you will classify as `true` only if all `k` of the KNN are classified as true.

Comment: @amit Low fp is indeed important. Since the data set is small, creating a new model every time will need less ime. But as the data set becomes large , what should be the choice ? Because the data set might have eveolved over time - perhaps even doubled in it's size - and hence the old model would be irrelevant.

Comment: There is also something called incremental learning. For example, decision trees (and decision forests) are eager learners, yet it is pretty simple to implement them in an incremental way, so each new example you will get along the way will be added to the model without the need to recalculate it.

Comment: Also: Is training time an issue? If the data set is small, the learning time is not expected to be too long as well

Comment: Well, as for now, I would say accuracy has a much higher priority. But in case a web based implementation is needed, time would become important as well. Then heuristics would come into play.